# Register Celery Class-based Task

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery

Python 3.x, Celery 4.x...

I have a class-based task.

`myproj/celery.py`

```
from celery import Celery

# django settings stuff...

app = Celery('myproj')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

`app1/tasks.py`

```
import celery

class EmailTask(celery.Task):
    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.do_something()
```

If I do:

```
$ celery worker -A myproj -l info
[tasks]
  . app2.tasks.debug_task
  . app2.tasks.test
```

So, the celery decorators work to register tasks, but the class-based task is not registered.

## How do I get the class-based tasks to register?

**Update 1:**

If I add the following lines to `app1/tasks.py`

```
from myproj.celery import app
email_task = app.tasks[EmailTask.name]
```

.

```
$ celery worker -A myproj -l info
  File "myproj/app1/tasks.py", line 405, in <module>
    email_task = app.tasks[EmailTask.name]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/app/registry.py", line 19, in __missing__
    raise self.NotRegistered(key)
celery.exceptions.NotRegistered
```

**Update 2:**

I am able to execute my task synchronously (`run`) via a wrapper. However, I cannot run the task async, i.e., via `delay`.

`app1/tasks.py`

```
@app.task
def email_task():
    """
    Wrapper to call class based task
    """
    task = EmailTask()
    # task.delay()  # Won't work!!!
    task.run()
```

.

```
$./manage.py shell
> from app1.tasks import EmailTask
> task1 = EmailTask()
> task1.run() # a-okay
> task2 = EmailTask()
> task2.delay() # nope
  <AsyncResult: 1c03bad9-169a-4a4e-a56f-7d83892e8bbc>

# And on the worker...
[2017-01-22 08:07:28,120: INFO/PoolWorker-1] Task app1.tasks.email_task[41e5bc7d-058a-400e-9f73-c853c0f60a2a] succeeded in 0.0701281649817247s: None
[2017-01-22 08:10:31,909: ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered task of type None.
The message has been ignored and discarded.
```

Comment: Hello, you can find your solution here https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3744

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can find full description [here](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3744), but for me it was enough to add

```
from myapp.celery import app
app.tasks.register(MyTaskTask())
```

Answer (score 24):

With `celery==4.2.1` I had to use the return value of `Celery.register_task()` as the task instance to call `delay()` on:

```
# my_app/tasks.py
import celery

from my_app.celery import app

class MyTask(celery.Task):
    def run(self):
        [...]

MyTask = app.register_task(MyTask())
```

Then to use it:

```
# my_app/app.py
from my_app.tasks import MyTask

[...]

MyTask.delay()
```

The solution was described in a [Github issue](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3874#issuecomment-285776060) and is [documented here](http://docs.celeryq.dev/en/4.0/whatsnew-4.0.html#the-task-base-class-no-longer-automatically-register-tasks).

Hth,
dtk

Answer (score 2):

I just spent a long time figuring out why my worker was crashing when I started it.

if you are receiving:
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'push'` 
when you start your worker

do NOT use
`app.tasks.register(MyTask())`

instead use:
`app.register_task(MyTask())`

see more here: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/7173

Note - this was done on celery 5.3.0

Comment: Additionally you should restart celery daemon after any change on tasks.

Answer (score 0):

`celery==5.4` you can try this way:

```
// tasks.py

from celery import Celery, Task

app = Celery('tasks', broker='redis://localhost:6379/0', backend='redis://localhost:6379/0')

class MyTask(Task):
    name = "my_task"
    
    def run(self, x, y):
        return x + y

my_task = app.register_task(MyTask())
```

Another module:

```
from tasks import my_task

my_task.delay(12, 34)
```