# How to solve celery 'Not Registered' Exception

Tags: django, asynchronous, redis, celery

> ```
> dev env
> django = 3.2.4
> celery = 5.2.3
> redis
> ```

I use Celery to asynchronously process. I'm using it for email transmission and AI Inference functions, but @sharedtask applied to email works well without any problems. However, the AI Inference function is different. Once successful and then the same action is performed, the 'Not registered' Exception is displayed. Why does this happen?
The success and failure of the same task are shown below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPjlS.png)

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your worker is not familiar with the `call_ai_engine_api_task`.

There are several ways to do that, for example:

```
app = Celery("my_app", broker=..., backend=..., include=["path.to.call_ai_engine_api_task", ..])
```

or with [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41794225/1011253).

You can then see the list of registered tasks in worker startup logs.